# How to implement and create a central Scoring server using iPhones to send updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, ios

I have been searching and googling different ways to build a central scoring server for a golf tournament but have not found any dead set answers on how I can do this.  What I'm looking for is some advice on how I should implement this.  I do have a background in programming in Objective-C as I have created a couple of iPhone apps and I'm not afraid of trying and learning new things.  I will explain what I envision and if I could get some suggestions on how to start, that would be great.

a.  My golf tournament would have about 80 people playing in it.

b.  I would have 5 volunteers with iPhones stationed around the golf course to collect scores from the players as they finish a couple of holes.

c.  The volunteer would enter the scores into an app on the iPhone.  The app would then send the scores to the central scoring server to update a giant leader board at the clubhouse.

My questions are what kind of database should I use?  I'll need something that is very user friendly as I'll need to be able to make quick changes to the database on the fly if required.  The iPhones will not share the same network as the central server as they would most likely be on 3G out on the golf course.  For now, the iPhone app that is sending scores to the server, will not be in the app store as I will build the app through an ad Hoc profile.

Any help, suggestions or advice would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What server languages/architectures are you used to?  How much time do you have?  What kind of changes will you need to make to the database on the fly?

Comment: 0 experience in server languages/architectures... I would have to learn it, therefore a language that is relatively easy to learn would be ideal.  I have just under a year to build the program.  Changes on the fly would include making and changing the draw of players up to an hour before the event is running.

Comment: I recommend google app engine.  It will be basically free for such a small app and can be programmed in either java or python.  They provide web tools for all object model management which make it easy to query, change, and add data.  I've done 4-5 apps which integrate mobile to cloud services and app engine is cheap scalable and relatively easy to implement services on.

Comment: @Dave. Thank you for your input! I will definitely look into that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would presumably need a hosted service of some sort that each instance of your iPhone app would send its data to. Typically those hosted services are implemented in other languages/technology stacks like Java, PHP, or Ruby/Rails. The server app would then persist data into a database: MySQL is a commonly used solution, but there are a lot of options with different strengths and weaknesses depending on your specific requirements.

If a hosted server application isn't somewhere you want to go, and if your requirements are simple enough, you could look into a file-based server solution. For example, you could build your iPhone app to place scores in a small file on a Dropbox folder and then write a standalone app that collects those small files and does whatever you want with the data.

Hope that helps

Comment: IMO a restful rails service would be easiest to implement and deploy.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your comments and ideas.  I will continue researching.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your opinion.  I will look into a restful rails service.

Answer (score 1):

If you have little experience with servers, you might also consider one of the new server-in-a-can services like parse, stackmob, or kinverse. There's quite a bit involved in building/maintaining a server, especially if you need it to scale.